# Java countdown time doesnt display correct time

Tags: java

Im currently working on a project that has a simple countdown where the user enters a time and it starts counting down from that time. it is GUI based and displays  the countdown to the user. ive managed to make it count down but its not displaying correctly.

**For example, if i enter 1min 30secs, it counts down from 1:30, to 1:01 then incorrectly displays 0:00 then it counts down from 0:59. it is correct until i get to a point where the minutes change to seconds and it doesnt display correctly for 1 second.**

Countdown class:

```
class countdownClass implements ActionListener { //counts down then beeps
            int counter;

            public countdownClass(int counter) {
                this.counter = counter;
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent sc) { //counts down every second
                counter--;
                if(counter >= 1) { //a simple countdown
                    if(counter > 9){ //this statement is for aestetic purpose as before
                        seconds.setText("" + counter);
                    }else{ 
                        seconds.setText("0" + counter);
                    }
                }

                else if(minutesNum >= 1 && counter <= 0){ //if minute exists carry on the countdown
                    // 1:01 - > 1:00 - > 0:59

                    int minuteUpdate = minutesNum - 1;
                    if (minutesNum < 9){
                        minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minutesNum));
                        seconds.setText("00");
                        if(counter <= 0){
                        minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minuteUpdate));
                        }
                    }else{
                        minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minutesNum));
                        seconds.setText("0" + Integer.toString(00));
                        minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minuteUpdate));
                    }
                    counter = 60;
                }

                else if(minutesNum == 0 && counter == 0) { //once the countdown ends plays a beep
                    timer.stop();
                    seconds.setText("00");
                    finish.setText("Time is up!");
                    start.setEnabled(true);
                    try{
                        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("ring.wav")));
                        clip.start();
                        soundPlay = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

could you please help me identify where the code is going wrong and provide me with a fix for it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you using a new variable `minutesUpdate` instead of decrementing `minutesNum` ?

Comment: This looks like a very convoluted way of proceeding. Why don't you just have a number of seconds (starting at 90) and get rid of `minutesNum` entirely?

Comment: Well the quick solution is to replace `int minuteUpdate = minutesNum - 1;` with `minutesNum--;`. But the answers are giving you a better implemented solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks a little over-engineered. Just convert the user-entered time into seconds and decrement that value every second. Then print the result with something like:

```
private static String secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(int time) {
  int minutes = time / 60;
  int seconds = time % 60;

  return String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
}
```

E.g. 1 minute 30 seconds is just 90 seconds. Pass `90` into the above method and you get `01:30`. If you need the minute and second values individually, it should be easy enough to edit that code example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the minutes digit displayed is minuteUdpate which is set to one less than MinutesNum.

```
                else if(minutesNum >= 1 && counter <= 0){ //if minute exists carry on the countdown
                // 1:01 - > 1:00 - > 0:59

                int minuteUpdate = minutesNum - 1;
                if (minutesNum < 9){
                    minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minutesNum));
                    seconds.setText("00");
                    if(counter <= 0){
                    minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minuteUpdate));
                    }
                }else{
                    minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minutesNum));
                    seconds.setText("0" + Integer.toString(00));
                    minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minuteUpdate));
                }
                counter = 60;
```

minutesNum is less than 9, and counter = 0 for 1:00, so this line should be done:

```
minutes.setText("0" + Integer.toString(minuteUpdate));
```

I'd remove that if block. The minutes number should not be decremented before the seconds number is changed to 60.

Answer (score 0):

For me, your code is useless complex.

What you should do:

1. Use two variables to save `minutes` and `seconds`.
2. The start value of there two variables will be what the users put (Examples if its 3:50, minutes will be 3, second will be 50)
3. Start a timer every second, scale 1 second from counter and if seconds is <= 0, scale minutes and put seconds to 59. If minutes is 0 and seconds.

It's just a concept to show my idea:

```
private static int minutes = 0;
private static int seconds = 5;

private static Timer timer;

private static TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (countdown())
            System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Finish!");
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
};

private static boolean countdown()
{
    seconds --;
    if (seconds < 0)
    {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;

        if (minutes == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);

}
```

You could work with seconds only and avoid the `minutes` variable.
(Example: 1 min => 60 seconds; and then use a method to fix it using division)

---

It's my first time i use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` so it could not be perfect.

```
private static int minutes = 0;
private static int seconds = 5;

private static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executorService;

private static boolean countdown()
{
    seconds --;
    if (seconds < 0)
    {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;

        if (minutes == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static Runnable task = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (countdown())
            System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Finish!");

            // by throwing an exception we will stop the countdown
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    executorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try
    {
        // schedulate again the countdown
        System.out.println("Wait 7 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Schedulate again");

    // since we work with the original values
    // we must reset it
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 5;

    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Remember: this code don't work if multi threads calls `countdown` method!

Anyway, you can use `executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` to restore the countdown.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have a question. How do you make it so the timer is restartable. Because it says task is already scheduled or cancelled. The timer can't be reset for another use or paused then carried on. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor? to avoid this problem. I edit my answer